# How to add NSDictionary to NSArray to use it in tableview

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

`NSDictionary *recipe = arrayOfPlist[i];`

that I use it in a for loop

and in a if statement I added this dictionary to an `NSArray` `results= [recipe allValues];` like this

and I segue it like this

```
     destViewController.filteredContent=results;
```

I checked it the results array is not null but when I compile it and try to go to a PageView with selected array I'm having this exception

```
 *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', 
reason: '[<__NSCFString 0x109268e40> valueForUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key recipeName.'
```

`RecipeName` is a key from my Dictionary which I use it to write to cell.

I couldn't see the problem so I came here.

---

It turned out that s not my real problem. The crash happened at the next view controller which is a pageViewController. I passed the results array and it should only have 1 elements in it but when i checked it it says the count 8= number of keys in my dictionaries. It added all of the keys as a unique array element and thats where the problem happened. There is really not a recipeName ...

how can i fix this??

```
<plist version="1.0">
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>category</key>
        <string>desert</string>
        <key>numberOfPerson</key>
        <string>3</string>
        <key>recipeImage</key>
        <string>asdd.jpg</string>
        <key>time</key>
        <string>15</string>
        <key>recipeName</key>
        <string>Puding</string>
        <key>recipeDetail</key>
```

the count is 8 for this reason. It consider each key as an array element.

Comment: Are you sure `NSDictionary *recipe = arrayOfPlist[i];` actually gives you a dictionary?

Comment: Yes i m sure       
NSArray *arrayOfPlist = [[NSArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];        
recipe = arrayOfPlist[i];

and in my header file

 property (strong,nonatomic) NSDictionary *recipe;

@runmad

Comment: so technically, `results` holds `allValues` of `arrayOfPlist[i]` which probably is a string. then in that case when you go to `PageView`, how do you handle `filteredContent`? it should be an `NSArray` and used somewhat in this manner: `[filteredContent objectAtIndex:0];` (_this is just speculation_)

Comment: results array is not a array of dictionaries. It's the all values of recipe. values for RecipeName is in the array??

Comment: @staticVoidMan i think that is my problem. since i searched the problem in wrong place.I segued the data and the crash happened at the tableViewController. When i checked the length of the filteredArray it says 8 where it should have been 1. So i think filteredArray just consider each key values as a unique element...

How can i go from here?

Comment: erm... i don't know what you have in mind for `PageView` and I don't know your plist structure but you can do something like this `results = @[@"recipeName"];` instead of `results= [recipe allValues];` or something along these lines

Comment: if that doesn't work then add a snippet of your plist structure and the for loop (_trim it down to the essentials_) to your question

Comment: @staticVoidMan that didn't work aswell. Added the plist structure the the question

Comment: so... what all data will you show in `PageView`? also... are there multiple `<dict>`s in the plist or just this one?

Comment: or... maybe you want this `results = @[recipe];` instead of `results= [recipe allValues];` (_shot in the dark_) and later in `PageView` something like `[[filteredContent objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"recipeName]"`

Comment: @staticVoidMan i love you man. yea that was the trick. Thnx so much

Comment: great :). i'll post an answer now or... you can delete this question :P

Comment: @staticVoidMan post the answer so i can up vote you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix your error, change

```
results = [recipe allValues];
```

to:

```
results = @[recipe];
```

---

### Explanation:

> <__NSCFString XxXXXXXXXXX> valueForUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key ...

The error tells us:

1. Object is a string
2. Method causing the error is `valueForUndefinedKey:` (*due to a `-valueForKey:`*)

   - since the string was not set up properly to handle `-valueForKey:`

For `-valueForKey:` to work, `NSString` will reference a value from a key (*which indicates that a specified key should have a related value*).
But in your case, `results = [recipe allValues];` has returned you an array of only strings and not key-value pairs (*i.e. not a dictionary*) and hence `valueForKey:@"recipeName"` will cause an error since the `recipeName` is taken as a key and it does not have a related value.

### Example:

```
//this will not cause the error
NSDictionary *dctTest = @{@"recipeName": @"Pancakes"};
NSString *strSuccess = [dctTest valueForKey:@"recipeName"];

//this will cause the error
NSArray *arrTest = @[@"Pancakes"];
NSString *strError = [arrTest valueForKey:@"recipeName"];
```

Comment: well the problem kinda continues.When i create my array with 

results=@[recipe] or results= @[arrayOfPlist[i]] i can only add one dictionary to the results array which is definitely not okey. SO there is again a problem of adding dictionary.Do you have any idea?

Comment: yes, you'd get only one dictionary (_so basically only one recipe_). If this is not what you expect, then what do you expect to see in `PageView`?

Comment: all recipes that fit the criteria.I managed to properly implement 3 filters but this one is really killing me.DO you have any idea.

What i need is like results=[arrayOfPlist[2],[arrayofPlist[6]] a way to add more to the final result array

Comment: @user3570579 : hm... then in that case, if your `for` loop + `if` loop is working correctly, you should change the `results` object to be an `NSMutableArray` object rather than `NSArray` and do `[results addObject:recipe];` instead of `results = @[recipe];` (_but then handle this change appropriately in `PageView` with something like: `[[filteredContent objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"recipeName"]`_)

Comment: that was the first thing i tried and for the reasons i don't know for sure the content of the array was always null or unusable guess i ll have to dig in.If you have any idea i m open to hear it :)

Comment: @user3570579 : post a new question regarding this and add all the relevant/related code and if no one answers, i'll surely look at it later. For now, just don't forget to do `results = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];` before beginning with the `for` loop.

Answer (score 1):

The error clearly says "There is no value for the key recipeName".

Just write the below code to make sure.

```
NSArray *arrayOfPlist = [[NSArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path]; 
recipe = arrayOfPlist[i]; 

NSString *myValue = [recipe valueForKey:@"recipeName"];
NSLog("value is %@", myValue);
```

Or Just try this and cross check the log

```
for (id key in dictionary)
{
    NSLog(@"key: %@, value: %@ \n", key, [dictionary objectForKey:key]);
}
```

Also, please check the xib file. verify that, there is no "recipeName" linked to your implementation file as IBOutlet.

Comment: Yea It gives me right answer so there is clearly something else going on

Comment: on the contrary there is indeed a recipeName but i don't know if you see my last edit.There is not a recipeName in the transferred array.Its really bizarre the things i m passing to segue is clear and perfect but when i take it to page view it doesn't work

Comment: could you please check the xib file? verify that, there is no "recipeName" linked to your implementation file as IBOutlet.

Comment: There are only 2 IBOutlet and none of them are in that name

Comment: could you send the sample app to "shamsutk87@gmail.com"

Comment: i don't think you will be able to understand my weirdly written codes but yea i will send it.Thnx for your attention

Comment: oh fixed the problem.  with this results = @[recipe]; 

Thnx anyway